# Gui opens for all players, but i did script in LocalScript

Tags: roblox

```
local prnt = script.Parent

game.Workspace.TeamChoose.Silents.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Name == "Right Leg" then
        prnt.Visible = true
        prnt.Silents.Visible = true
        prnt.Phantoms.Visible = false
    end
end)
```

i want to do it visible only for local player, but it opens for local and other Players
**How do i Fix it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place a script inside of the part, listen for the Touched event, find the player from the Touched event, and then give them the GUI!

```
local guiName = "" -- place gui name here

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    local player = game:GetService("Players"):GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
    if player then
        local gui = player:WaitForChild("PlayerGui"):WaitForChild(guiName)
        gui.Visible = true
        gui.Silents.Visible = true
        gui.Phantoms.Visible = true
    end
end)
```